# Why do JavaScript embeds toggle between HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, http

I've noticed that JavaScript embeds from sites like Google Analytics check the current page's protocol and then write their `<script>` tag to match. I understand that you can receive security errors for embedding HTTP inside of an HTTPS page but is there any reason not to make all `<script>` calls to Google Analytics HTTPS? Does embedding HTTPS inside of an HTTP page cause a problem?

Comment: (unrelated tip) if you use `//` as the protocol instead of `http://` or `https://` the browser uses the one being used for the page itself, which avoids the hackery you mention. I wonder why Analytics don't do that.

Comment: I read somewhere that there is a bug with '//' in IE 5. Perhaps that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS inside one HTTP page doesnt cause problems.

One reason to prefer HTTP requests is performace.

Normally HTTP requests responder faster (and lighter to server) than HTTPS.

So, when is possible, prefer to use HTTP.